# Javascript: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Tags: javascript, php

I have a dropdown list on my php page, filled with data from MySQL Database and i want to sort it alphabetically, but i get this error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL".

What am I doing wrong?

**HTML/PHP**

```
//Somewhere on my form...
echo '<select name=\"dropdownlist\" onclick=\"sortlist(this.value)\">';
```

**Javascript Function:**

```
function sortlist(formtag)
{
    var cl = document.getElementById(formtag);
    var clTexts = new Array();

    for(i = 2; i < cl.length; i++)
    {
        clTexts[i-2] =
            cl.options[i].text.toUpperCase() + "," +
            cl.options[i].text + "," +
            cl.options[i].value;
    }

    clTexts.sort();

    for(i = 2; i < cl.length; i++)
    {
        var parts = clTexts[i-2].split(',');

        cl.options[i].text = parts[1];
        cl.options[i].value = parts[2];
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont undestand the downvote! :S
A user answered but now its gone... -.-

It seems we can't have doubts around here... people start dowvoting!!

Comment: You mean inspect like this?
http://img823.imageshack.us/img823/8549/sz6g.png

I wouldnt ask before that!

Comment: on which line you get the error?

Comment: Well it seems some users here want to downvote everything, I dont want to get downvotes for spam this forum too. Thank you sir!

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance! :)
So, you tell me to start a new question... and now you tell me that there are related question already... Im new here, tell me what to do sir.

Plus i though this was a forum to help people learn how to program and helping solve problems. My question had some code and was in an intelligent manner. People downvote just because it was an easy answer (for them)

Comment: @Colin and for someone that says we need to ask in an intelligent manner and some research first and have questions like this "In Javascript, what is the difference between indexOf() and search()?" I don't know what to say... maybe you should do some research first!

Comment: Ok thank you for your attention. I keep my opinion. Users downvote because the answer was "pretty obvious" to them. If what you say is true, then answers like i had here from some users "Answer is pretty obvious" etc... are very bad, beucase I don't see what that helps for future users like me with same problem. I think this forum needs to downvote answers too, not only questions.

Comment: @Colin  didn't appreciate neither when you said something like"question need to be in an intelligence manner" because there is no problem with my question. I have seen worst...

Comment: @Colin problem solved. Thank you for your attention and your time, but now I have "fear" to question something on this forum! If you are one of the people behind this project, you guys should allow downvote answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the string is within single quotes, you not need to escape double quotes. Also, use "onchange" in `<select>` tag. Try this:

```
echo '<select name="dropdownlist" onchange="sortlist(this.value)">';
```

Mistake in javascript code, the: `var cl = document.getElementById(formtag);` can contain a single element, so, `cl.length` is not higher than 1.

Comment: Thank you sir! That solved the problem but now I have another :S
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null "

Something with my function parameter i supose.

Comment: You mean I need an array like var cl[] ? I've tried that didnt work.

Comment: The logic in your javascript code is wrong. `sortlist(this.value)` passes the value of selected option, but you use it as the id of an element, than traverses an arra with options from that element. All the code /logic must be rewritten according to what you want.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your attention. I'll figure out before i get downvotes till reach zero! Thank you once again.